# Query with t(n) and multiple cross joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Am trying to understand this query from a Stackoverflow thread:

```
--create test table
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable(
      Col1 nchar(4000) NOT NULL
    , Col2 nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL
    );

--load 10000 rows (about 2.8GB)
WITH 
    t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
    ,t16M AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t256 AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
SELECT REPLICATE(N'X', 4000), REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 10000)
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 100000;
GO

--run query in loop (expect parallel execution plan with many read-ahead and LOB page reads)
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @RowCount int, @Iteration int = 1;
WHILE @Iteration <= 100
BEGIN
    CHECKPOINT;
    DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
    SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE Col2 LIKE 'X%';
    RAISERROR('Iteration %d completed',0,1,@Iteration) WITH NOWAIT; --display progress message
    SET @Iteration += 1;
END;
GO
```

1. I especially couldn't understand this portionof the t-sql query :

   ```
   --load 10000 rows (about 2.8GB)
   WITH 
       t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
       ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
       ,t16M AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t256 AS c)
   INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
   SELECT REPLICATE(N'X', 4000), REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 10000)
   FROM t16M
   WHERE num <= 100000;
   GO
   ```
2. Why do we have a "With" below "--load 10000rows..." ; what does that "with" do? is it part of the 'create' statement?
3. regarding this insert statement:

   ```
   INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
   SELECT REPLICATE(N'X', 4000), REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 10000)
   FROM t16M
   WHERE num <= 100000;
   ```

   Wouldn't just

   ```
   INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
   FROM t16M
   WHERE num <= 100000;
   ```

   do? Wouldn't the above take the first 10000 rows from t16M and insert into dbo.TestTable? Why are we doing that "select..."? What is the implication of that?
   I understand that `REPLICATE(N'X', 4000)` would put `X` 4000 times in `Col1`, `REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 10000)` would put `X` 10000 times in `Col2`. If we are doing this, then why select from t16M? or if we are selecting from t16M, then why do this replicate thing?
4. what does
   @RowCount = COUNT(*)
   do? Assign num of rows in the table to a variable called 'RowCount'? Is it the same as '@@RowCount'? I don't think it can be.

Answer (score 5):

I''ll reformat the code for better understanding:

```
WITH t4 AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n)
)
,t256 AS(
    SELECT 0 AS n 
    FROM t4 AS a 
    CROSS JOIN t4 AS b 
    CROSS JOIN t4 AS c 
    CROSS JOIN t4 AS d
)
,t16M AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num 
    FROM t256 AS a 
    CROSS JOIN t256 AS b 
    CROSS JOIN t256 AS c
)
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
SELECT REPLICATE(N'X', 4000), REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 10000)
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 100000;
```

The 3 cascading `CTE`made up a `Tally Table` or others called `Numbers Table`. This is composed of sequential numbers from 1 up to some number.

This one generates 4 rows with 0 value:

```
WITH t4 AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n)
)
```

Then it is `CROSS JOIN`ed to itself 4 times thus generating `4 * 4 * 4 * 4` or `4^4` or `256` rows, thus the alias `t256`. Again `t256` is `CROSS JOIN`ed to itself 3 times producing `16,777,216` rows thus the alias `t16M`.
If you do a `SELECT * FROM t16M`, you can verify that it returns over 16M rows.

This is used then to insert 100000 rows into the `TestTable`, as evidenced by the where clause:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
SELECT REPLICATE(N'X', 4000), REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 10000)
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 100000
```

Some may use a `WHILE` loop in attempt to do this, that is insert 100000 rows into a table. The `Tally Table` is a great way to do this in a set-based fashion. For more info, read this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

---

**Question #2**
The `WITH` keyword below the `CREATE` statement marks the declaration of a [Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx).

**Question #3**
I believe the query below will produce a syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 100000;
```

This, on the other hand, will not.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable WITH(TABLOCKX) (Col1, Col2)
SELECT REPLICATE(N'X', 4000), REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 10000)
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 100000;
```

What this query does is `INSERT` 100000 rows, composed of 2 columns, whose values are continuous strings of 'X's. Remember that `t16M` is our `Tally Table` which consists of sequence of numbers from 1 up to 16M+. We do not use the values of the `Tally Table` for the insert, we only use the presence of its rows to limit the number of inserts.

**Question #4** You're right when you said `@RowCount = COUNT(*)` assigns the number of rows to the variable.

```
SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TestTable WHERE Col2 LIKE 'X%';
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

However, the above statements are not the same. [@@ROWCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. If we put it inside the `WHILE` loop right after the `SELECT @RowCount`, it will return 1, as only 1 row is affected. However, if we put it directly after the `INSERT` statement, it will return the same as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TestTable`.

Comment: am still stuck with a few things (edited the original post above with my questions (2) & (3)). Can you please help?