# Fill Missing Dates In a Date-Sequenced in SQL using Tally Table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports

I have a table in database with numbers of tenants, each tenant lists a record of their sales per date. There are instance where in a tenant has NO SALES in particular date/s, therefore the date with no sales has NO RECORD in the table breaking a proper date sequence. Please see the sample table for illustration below:

[image]

I used this select query in SQL to display the output above

```
select tenant, date, sales
from tblSales
where date between '01/01/2015' and '01/05/2014'
```

What I need as a correct output: display complete date based on the selected date range on the where clause, when tenant has no record in a particular date, the query should add a record of date in that particular tenant and just add null value in the sales column like in this image:

[image]

1. as my initial solution, I thought of creating a temp table inserting a sequence of date based on the date range selected and use that to left join with the actual table.

**Here's what I have started:**

```
@dateFrom datetime  = '02/01/2015',
@dateTo date = '02/05/2015'    

declare @MaxNumDays int
declare @Counter int
                
set @Counter = 0
set @MaxNumDays = DATEDIFF(day, @dateFrom  , @dateto) + 1                
    
create table #DSRTdate (
    Date datetime
)
    
WHILE @Counter < @MaxNumDays
BEGIN
    insert into #DSRTdate (Date) values (DATEADD(day,@Counter,@dateFrom ))
    SET @Counter += 1
END
```

I used the above codes to get and insert in a temporary table the sequence data from the use selection, in the above case, it inserts 02/01/2015, 02/02/2015, 02/03/2015, 02/04/2015, AND 02/05/2015

```
select tenantcode, date, sales
into #DSRT2
from DAILYMOD 
where (date between @dateFrom and @dateTo)
   
select *
from #dsrtdate a
left join #DSRT2 b on a.date = b.date
order by b.tenantcode, a.date
```

Then I used left join to display the missing dates but this results only to ONE TENANT only and it makes also the tenantname null. Like this:

[image]

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your   #1 seems to be quite acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using a [**Tally Table**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

Basically, you use the `Tally Table` to generate sequence of dates from `@startDate` to `@endDate` and `CROSS JOIN` it to `DISTINCT Item` to generate all `Date`-`Item` combination. Then, the result will be `LEFT-JOIN`ed to `tblSales` to achieve the desired output.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c1d3/3/0)

```
DECLARE
    @startDate  DATE = '20140101',
    @endDate    DATE = '20140105';

WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) + 1) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
)
,CteAllDates(Item, dt) AS(
    SELECT x.Item, DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @startDate)
    FROM Tally
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT Item 
        FROM tblSales
        WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    ) AS x
)
SELECT d.*, ts.Sales
FROM CteAllDates d
LEFT JOIN tblSales ts
    ON ts.Item = d.Item
    AND ts.Date = d.dt
WHERE
    ts.[Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
ORDER BY d.Item, d.dt
```

---

Here is an alternative. Instead of the cascading `CTE`s, use `sys.columns` to generate the `Tally Table`.:

```
DECLARE
    @startDate  DATE = '20140101',
    @endDate    DATE = '20140105';

WITH Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) + 1) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM sys.columns a, sys.columns b
)
,CteAllDates(Item, dt) AS(
    SELECT x.Item, DATEADD(DAY, N - 1, @startDate)
    FROM Tally
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT Item 
        FROM tblSales
        WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    ) AS x
)
SELECT d.*, ts.Sales
FROM CteAllDates d
LEFT JOIN tblSales ts
    ON ts.Item = d.Item
    AND ts.Date = d.dt
WHERE
    ts.[Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
ORDER BY d.Item, d.dt
```

---

**Result**

```
|    Item |         dt |  Sales |
|---------|------------|--------|
| tenant1 | 2014-01-01 |    100 |
| tenant1 | 2014-01-02 |    100 |
| tenant1 | 2014-01-03 |    100 |
| tenant1 | 2014-01-04 |   NULL |
| tenant1 | 2014-01-05 |    100 |
| tenant2 | 2014-01-01 |    100 |
| tenant2 | 2014-01-02 |   NULL |
| tenant2 | 2014-01-03 |   NULL |
| tenant2 | 2014-01-04 |    100 |
| tenant2 | 2014-01-05 |   NULL |
| tenant3 | 2014-01-01 |    100 |
| tenant3 | 2014-01-02 |   NULL |
| tenant3 | 2014-01-03 |    100 |
| tenant3 | 2014-01-04 |   NULL |
| tenant3 | 2014-01-05 |    100 |
```

Comment: Question, what does the  SELECT 1 UNION ALL part mean, is the number of times it has repeated fixed?

Comment: I suggest you read the article referenced in the question. Also, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359086/query-with-tn-and-multiple-cross-joins/28359228#28359228

Comment: I am finding this hard to understand and implement on my code, but still trying. Are there any ways or alternatives?

Comment: Please see also my updated question with codes I have started, maybe you could improve that @wewesthemenace

Comment: My answer is basically the same as what you're trying to accomplish. Only that, my approach is set-based and yours is in RBAR fashion. This is so much faster than your implementation. I suggest you read on the article I referenced.

Comment: I have used your sys.column method, and just replace some table name and column name from the actual names in my coding, but it did not work :( @wewe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76506/discussion-between-wewesthemenace-and-rickyprogrammer).

Comment: HELPFUL, i prefer to use the second option. Thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 0):

I ***love*** wewesthemenace answer! Up-voted and have saved it for future reference. Here is another suggestion. Use this code in SQL command from Crystal. Left outer join to your table sales. Its long. Its tedious. But its easier to understand if you aren't an SQL expert which describes me pretty well :) If you figured out his answer and it works then disregard this solution.

Note: the from clause isn't serving any function except to satisfy the requirement of having a from clause in an SQL statement like this. If tblSales is a large table consider using one from your database which has less data and still left outer join to tblSales.

```
    select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','01') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','02') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','03') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','04') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','05') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','06') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','07') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','08') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','09') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','10') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','11') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','12') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','13') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','14') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','15') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','16') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','17') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','18') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','19') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','20') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','21') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','22') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','23') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','24') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','25') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','26') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','27') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','28') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','29') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','30') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
UNION
select distinct
cast(concat(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()),'-',DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()),'-','31') as DATE) as salesdate
from tblSales
```

Comment: If you need a month other than current month, which as I thought about it I realized that is likely, replace GETDATE() with a parameter field.

Comment: Yes, I already understand the answer of @wewe. Thanks though for this effort for sure if ever other people get to have the same problem as mine, for sure your answer could help as reference. Thanks