# SQL Server 2012 using temp table of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, inner-join

First at all thanks for reading. I have a situation that I'm not able to solve.

I've created a stored procedure that creates a temp table with the days between two dates.

Example: if I pass `'2015-07-20'` & `'2015-07-25'` as parameters to the stored procedure, it will create a table with 5 days from the 20th to the 25th of July 2015.

What I need to do is use this temp table in a join case, something like this query.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM control
 INNER JOIN
     (my table returned from sp  => exec calendario_dias ... ) ON dia = cta_dia
```

This is the stored procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[calendario_dias]
        (@fecha_ini date,
        @fecha_fin date)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('#dias_calendar') AND type in (N'U'))
       DROP TABLE [dbo].#dias_calendar

    CREATE TABLE #dias_calendar(dia date)   

    WHILE @fecha_ini <= @fecha_fin
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #dias_calendar (dia) 
           SELECT @fecha_ini

        SET @fecha_ini = CONVERT(date, dateadd(day, 1, @fecha_ini))
    END 

    SELECT dia 
    FROM #dias_calendar
END
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [tally table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29933492/119477)  instead of a temp table

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach with a Tally-Table function (you can use this everywhere...)

EDIT: Uses an own function now. You can use and join this function wherever you want...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRunningNumbers](@anzahl INT=10000000, @StartAt INT=0)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 ^ 1 = 10 rows
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b), -- 10 ^ 8 = 10,000,000 rows
CteTally AS(
    SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@anzahl,1000000)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) -1 + ISNULL(@StartAt,0) As Nmbr
    FROM E8
)
SELECT * FROM CteTally;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateLine
(
     @d1 DATETIME
    ,@d2 DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,runningNumbers.Nmbr,@d1) AS DateRunning
FROM dbo.GetRunningNumbers(ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,@d1,@d2))+1,0) AS runningNumbers

GO

--Always three dates with one obejct...
SELECT  name,object_id,DateRunning
FROM sys.objects 
CROSS APPLY dbo.DateLine({ts'2015-07-01 00:00:00'},{ts'2015-07-03 00:00:00'}) AS dl
ORDER BY object_id,DateRunning
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.DateLine;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetRunningNumbers;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

[Temporary Tables](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/) are local to your connection and are dropped when no longer in use.They work and act like regular tables.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE test1(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Column1] [int] NULL,
    [Column2] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


insert into test1(column1,column2) values(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)
```

And the Joining:

```
create table #tbl1(Id bigint Identity,value1 varchar(max))

insert into #tbl1(value1) values('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')

select * from test1 join #tbl1 on test1.Id=#tbl1.Id
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7bc5/2)

Answer (score 0):

explicit answer

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION calendario_dias
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@fecha_ini date, 
@fecha_fin date

)
RETURNS
@dias_calendar TABLE
(
-- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
dia date
)
AS
BEGIN
-- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set

WHILE @fecha_ini <= @fecha_fin
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @dias_calendar
SELECT @fecha_ini
SET @fecha_ini = CONVERT(date, dateadd(day, 1, @fecha_ini))
END

RETURN
END
GO
```

and then :

```
SELECT *
FROM control
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[calendario_dias](@fecha_ini date,@fecha_fin date)
ON dia = cta_dia
```

Comment: Wasn't it you who suggested an **inline** function? An inline function is a single-statement call, no WHILE and other procedural code... Just pure, set based SQL...

Comment: you are new here, just one hint: If you've given an answer already it'd be better do edit this one than to start a new one...

Comment: @Shnugo well sorry i didnt see his TSQL at first sight and because of this i published a new answer

Comment: Please do not use WHILE loops unless you have to. This can easily be accomplished with no loops via an inline TVF (as shown by @Shnugo). Inline TVFs are much more efficient.