# How to get a running total by date while inserting dates for days when no transactions occurred

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of transactions that I have successfully queried to get a running total of the amounts per day, partitioned by scenario_id as shown in the following example:

Tables:

**Transactions**

| Transaction Date | Scenario_id | transaction_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/19/2022 | 00000000 | $.01 |
| 5/25/2022 | 00000000 | $5.00 |
| 5/18/2022 | 10000000 | $50 |
| 5/19/2022 | 00000000 | $.01 |
| 5/25/2022 | 00000000 | $5.00 |
| 5/18/2022 | 10000000 | $50 |

**Filters**

| starting_cash | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $50,000 | 5/19/2022 | 5/25/2022 |

Code:

```
SELECT   transaction_date, scenario_id, SUM(transaction_amount) AS net_daily,
                             (SELECT   filters.starting_cash
                                FROM         filters) + SUM(SUM(transaction_amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY scenario_id
ORDER BY transaction_date) AS forecasted_cash
FROM         Transactions
WHERE     transaction_date >=
                             (SELECT   filters.start_date
                                FROM         filters)
GROUP BY transaction_date, scenario_id
```

**Current Result**

| Transaction Date | Scenario_id | net_daily | Forecasted_cash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/19/2022 | 00000000 | $.02 | $50,000.02 |
| 5/25/2022 | 00000000 | $10 | $50,010.02 |
| 5/18/2022 | 10000000 | $100 | $50,100 |

However, I would like to have all empty dates in the timeline that is filtered for to be populated with $0 net daily while carrying on the forecasted cash running total from the day before:

*Desired Result*

| Transaction Date | Scenario_id | net_daily | Forecasted_cash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/19/2022 | 00000000 | $.02 | $50,000.02 |
| 5/20/2022 | 00000000 | $0. | $50,000.02 |
| 5/21/2022 | 00000000 | $0. | $50,000.02 |
| 5/22/2022 | 00000000 | $0. | $50,000.02 |
| 5/23/2022 | 00000000 | $0. | $50,000.02 |
| 5/24/2022 | 00000000 | $0. | $50,000.02 |
| 5/25/2022 | 00000000 | $10 | $50,010.02 |
| 5/18/2022 | 10000000 | $100 | $50,100 |
| 5/19/2022 | 10000000 | $0 | $50,100 |
| 5/20/2022 | 10000000 | $0 | $50,100 |
| 5/21/2022 | 10000000 | $0 | $50,100 |
| 5/22/2022 | 10000000 | $0 | $50,100 |
| 5/23/2022 | 10000000 | $0 | $50,100 |
| 5/24/2022 | 10000000 | $0 | $50,100 |
| 5/25/2022 | 10000000 | $0 | $50,100 |

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds to me like a typical use for a Tally table. This question is similar to yours, make sure to check out the article linked in the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933375/fill-missing-dates-in-a-date-sequenced-in-sql-using-tally-table

Comment: for `Scenario_id 10000000 5/18/2022`, how do you get `Forecasted_cash` of `$50,100` when the Filters `$50,000` only starts from `5/19/2022` ?

Comment: @Squirrel That was an oversight on my part when inputting example information. the 5/18 should be filtered out in this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a list of dates and then left join to the `Transactions` table.

CTE `filters_dates` recursively generates the list of dates. CTE `scenario` gets the distinct `Scenario_id`. CTE `trans` summarize the transactions by `date` & `scenario_id` as you have multiple entry with same date. The final result of `Forecasted_cash` is basically a running total of `Transaction _Amount` + `starting_cash`

```
with 
filters_dates as
(
    select starting_cash, start_date, end_date, trans_date = start_date
    from   Filters
    union all
    select starting_cash, start_date, end_date, trans_date = dateadd(day, 1, trans_date)
    from   filters_dates
    where  trans_date < end_date
),
scenario as
(
    select distinct Scenario_id 
    from   Transactions
),
trans as
(
    select trans_date = transaction_date, Scenario_id, trans_amount = sum(transaction_amount)
    from   Transactions
    group by transaction_date, Scenario_id
)
select f.trans_date, 
       s.Scenario_id,
       net_daily = isnull(t.trans_amount, 0),
       Forecasted_cash = f.starting_cash
                       + sum(isnull(t.trans_amount, 0)) over (partition by s.Scenario_id
                                                                  order by f.trans_date)
from   filters_dates f
       cross join scenario s
       left join trans t  on  f.trans_date = t.Trans_Date
                          and s.Scenario_id = t.Scenario_id
order by s.Scenario_id, f.trans_date;
```